# MonoTouch compiler directive for iPhone Simulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, compiler-directives

Does anyone know the compiler directive I'd use in MonoTouch to see if I'm running in the iPhone simulator? Can't find any info anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no compiler directive (conditional compilation symbol) to determine if you're running in the iPhone simulator or on a device.

You can however determine it at runtime, using this code:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
static bool InSimulator ()
{
    return Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
}
```

This is from here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/General/Projects/Environment_Checks

Comment: If you need to, you can add your own compile time symbol in the Compiler options on each project settings

Comment: It is now in Xamarin.iOS:     `static bool InSimulator ()
  {
   return ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Arch == ObjCRuntime.Arch.SIMULATOR;
  }`    https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.Arch/